# prevent any update or delete from table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have a table where I added a boolean column `done`
When this column is `True` I want to prevent any unautorized action (delete, update) on the row.

I wrote this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER productstock_beforeupdate
  BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trig()

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trig()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
begin
    if TG_OP='UPDATE' or TG_OP='DELETE' then
        if old.done=true then
                    raise exception 'cant do that';
            return null;
        end if;
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$
```

If autorized transaction wants to change data it will have first to disable this trigger.

This idea should work however when I try to delete a row with

```
done=False
```

it returns me "0 rows deleted" and does not perform the delete.

Any idea what is wrong with my trigger?

Comment: If I remove the trigger the delete works.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name both delete and update does not work in case done=false

Comment: DML? I think that this doesnt work because the trigger is before rather than AFTER

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name check edit now... But this is the wierd stuff.. if you look at the code in the question it still doesn't work. when I change it to "AFTER" it works like a charm. I think it doesn't do the return null .. it jumps out at the exception and abort everything.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the fact that for an UPDATE to go through you need to return the `NEW` record. However for a DELETE to go through, you need to return the `OLD`record.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> Thus, if the trigger function wants the triggering action to succeed normally without altering the row value, NEW (or a value equal thereto) has to be returned [...] Note that NEW is null in DELETE triggers, so returning that is usually not sensible. The usual idiom in DELETE triggers is to return OLD.

So your trigger function should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trig()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
begin
  -- no need to check for the action here as the trigger
  -- will only fire for UPDATE or DELETE
  if old.done then
    raise exception 'cant do that';
    return null;
  end if;

  if TG_OP='UPDATE' then 
    return new;
  end if; 

  if TG_OP='DELETE' then
    return old;
  end if;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

When the trigger allows `DELETE` it should return `old`. In case of `UPDATE` it returns `new`.
If it raises an exception it do not need to return anything.

```
create or replace function trig()
  returns trigger language plpgsql as
$$
begin
    if old.done then
        raise exception 'cant do that';
    end if;
    if tg_op = 'DELETE' then
        return old;
    else
        return new;
    end if;
end $$;
```